# Instruct apache not to decode URL

Tags: apache, apache2, httpd.conf, apache-config

So I have a URL like http://example.com/params/color_rgb(0%2C0%2C250%2C0.5)

But apache is forwarding it like (http://example.com/params/color_rgb(0,0,250,0.5)) after decoding which I don't want.

How can I restrict apache from doing this. I have apache 2.2.31 in my ubuntu.

Comment: Can you show your current "forwarding" configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try the "nocanon" option on the ProxyPass directives you're presumably using.